# list users by a specific role with laravel\spatie

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I want to list in a `<select>` all users with specific role `doctor`, i'm using laravel spatie library

```
<label for="select_doctor">{{__("Select doctor") }}</label>
<select name="select_doctor" id="select_doctor" class="form-control">
  <option value="" selected disabled>----- * ----</option>

  @foreach (App\User::all()->hasRole('doctor') as $doctor)
    <option value="">{{ __($doctor->person->name) }}</option>
  @endforeach

</select>
```

But I get this error
`Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::hasRole does not exist`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [specified in their docs](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/basic-usage/basic-usage), you can simply use `User::role('role_name')->get()` to get all users with the specific role.

```
@foreach (App\User::role('doctor')->get() as $doctor)
  <option value="">{{ __($doctor->person->name) }}</option>
@endforeach
```

As a side note, you should do such condition checkings from your controller itself and pass the $doctors list to your blade